# How do i migrate my session id generated from a PHP web page to a JSP one?

Tags: php, jsp

a php login page will generate a session id which i require to be passed to a jsp web server.
i also wish to use this session id on multiple web pages based on different platforms. how do i go ahead with it?
also which technology, if not php, will be best suited for the same ?

Comment: is your php & jsp script on same server?

Comment: Both of these are on different servers.

Comment: i am looking to create a web page to generate the session-id for already existing 2 web-based applications running on different servers. existing applications being jsp-based on tomcat and other being php-based running on Apache.

Comment: my primary concern as of now is to just fetch the Session-id of the Login JSP web-appln from my PHP web-page. Is it possible.. just like tamper data on browser; can i do the same through a php based web-page ? how ?

Comment: Please share all your comments on your question. That way anyone reading it can quickly have a better understanding of your problem and what you want to achieve, therefore, you will get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really use the same session id in the context of different servers and technologies. If you want to achieve something like you are describing, you should look at [Single sign on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) implementations as, for instance, [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas), which offers implementations for different platforms.

Furthermore, what you asked for sounds like a really dangerous idea. You should never use the session id alone to identify a user but rather rely on the mentioned technologies to achieve this.

Comment: will single sign-on require me to restructure the existing web-pages and web-apps ?

Comment: thanks a lot for your repLy !
i am looking to create a web page to generate the session-id for already existing 2 web-based applications. existing applications being jsp based and other being php based.

Comment: Yes, SSO will most likely introduce a 3rd player in your application: one that handles logins and tells your other apllications that a certain user (and which) is actually authenticated. This is for sure some effort, but at least a secure way to transparently have your user logged in two systems. Besides I doubt (or hope) that your applications let you hijack a session only based on some id that you sniffed from somewhere.

Comment: By this discussion it occurs to me that SSO is fully secured and best suited but it will involve higher level of restructuring. 
Yes i guess i need to generate some cookies and will involve browser related stuff to use session-id successfully.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the session ID via URL

```
<?PHP $session_id = session_id(); ?>
<a href="nextpage.jsp?session_id=<?PHP echo htmlspecialchars($session_id); ?>">
```

and then back using

```
<a href="phppage.php?session_id={{whatever language mechanism to pass the $session_id back}}">
```

then in the receiving PHP page

```
<?PHP session_id($_GET['session_id']); ?>
```

While this passes the ID (which is what was asked for) you will not have access to the contents of the session, so not sure of the value or what your intended use is.

Comment: as Dirk mentioned...  you need to be careful about passing/validating sessions in this manner.  you open the door for hijacking or other security vulnerabilities.

Comment: i am looking to create a web page to generate the session-id for already existing 2 web-based applications. existing applications being jsp based and other being php based.

Comment: You can pass the id around, but jsp would not be able to access an data stored in the PHP session and vice versa.  To allow such would be an incredible security vulnerability.  You could create a mechanism to package up the PHP session values and pass them onto the JSP pages (and in reverse) to allow them to be reloaded in, but this strikes me as overly onerous.  Another alternative might be to create your own session mechanism, a file with a light markup or XML structure, which you could then access and share between the applications?

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave. Really helpful feed from your side.
I am really keen to look onto such an XML structure as an example.

Comment: YAML may be a place to start, PHP and JSP support.  Has some quirks that you will need to consider.

Comment: that is all concerns if i wish to pass the session-id.
my primary concern as of now is to just fetch the Session-id of the Login JSP web-appln from my PHP web-page. Is it possible.. just like tamper data on browser; can i do the same through a php based web-page ? how ?